# Lock Acquisition Order in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, deadlock

I need a clear picture about lock acquisition order when performing certain queries. Below is the example, I tried.

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                        |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TestA | CREATE TABLE `TestA` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Within a transaction, I perform,

```
delete from TestA where id in (7,1);
```

My doubt is when getting record locks, will it get based on the order given in the list(7,1) or based on the table scan(1,7). Or is there any other factors determining this lock acquisition order?

Also, I checked data_locks in performance_schema and the result was;

```
+--------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| ENGINE | ENGINE_LOCK_ID                   | ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID | THREAD_ID | EVENT_ID | OBJECT_SCHEMA | OBJECT_NAME | PARTITION_NAME | SUBPARTITION_NAME | INDEX_NAME | OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN | LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE     | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
+--------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
| INNODB | 5254385560:563294:5198889928     |               9915434 |      5974 |      695 | test          | testa       | NULL           | NULL              | NULL       |            5198889928 | TABLE     | IX            | GRANTED     | NULL      |
| INNODB | 5254385560:562138:4:2:5201207320 |               9915434 |      5974 |      695 | test          | testa       | NULL           | NULL              | PRIMARY    |            5201207320 | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 1         |
| INNODB | 5254385560:562138:4:5:5201207320 |               9915434 |      5974 |      695 | test          | testa       | NULL           | NULL              | PRIMARY    |            5201207320 | RECORD    | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED     | 7         |
+--------+----------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From this table, should I conclude the locking order was 1,7? Or will it vary in some cases?

Comment: It MAY vary. In most cases the plan builder/optimiser sorts the values list in WHERE IN, it seems (at least when it is short enough, not more than ~10 values). This is reasonable when the expression which is tested against the values list is indexed because this may improve the query.

Comment: Since it is common to have dualing `IN` clauses, the Optimizer will usually sort the `IN` list.  That way, conflicts are likely to be delayed (cf  `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`) instead of deadlocking.

Comment: MySQL lets you say `DELETE ... WHERE id IN (7, 1) ORDER BY id` and it will do 1 then 7.